# Why isn't the listener bound to the object I am assigning it to?

Tags: java, libgdx, listener, event-listener, hashcode

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize[0]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mapSize[1]; j++) {
        hashCodes[i][j] = new Image(emptyField);
        int[] targetField = new int[2];
        targetField[0] = i;
        targetField[1] = j;
        hashCodes[i][j].addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Empty Field clicked" + Arrays.toString(targetField));
                for (Image[] imageRow : hashCodes) {
                    for (Image actualImage : imageRow) {
                        System.out.print(actualImage.hashCode() + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if (MarvelousMashup.useInfinityStone) {
                    MarvelousMashup.useInfinityStone = false;
                    MainMenu.client.getMessageHandler().sendUseInfinityStoneRequest
                            (MarvelousMashup.activeCharacter,
                                    getActualEntity(MarvelousMashup.activeCharacter).getPosition(),
                                    targetField,
                                    getStone(MarvelousMashup.useInfinityStoneID));
                }
            }
        });
        tempField.addActor(hashCodes[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I am assigning a listener to each Actor. But no matter what empty field I click the clicked field is still the same for me every time although each Actor is a different one.

```
Empty Field clicked[5, 5]
817686795 1047478056 2115628016 611643685 1935122449 872826668 
91323447 110053477 1209411469 1320105604 1076984738 1006751649 
1171434979 1920907467 970535245 194481424 1534755892 1548081008 
753321708 464400749 343563528 1719072416 2092801316 376635015 
1344697180 28597262 300983713 284686302 1940445711 1356840024 
1142347343 1810923540 1581078471 1932332324 33233312 1860491691
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because as far as I understand it, each actor should get their own listener and not all of them the same listener.

Comment: Why do you say each actor has a different listener?  They all look the same to me.  What are you seeing that leads you to conclude the actors are the same?  We're only seeing the output of one listener here.  What should be different?  What are you doing in the code that makes each listener different?

Comment: @markspace I am adding a new Image to the 2d Array and assigning them a listener. While essentially the listeners all need to do the same thing, what needs to be different about them is the `targetField`. And whenever I create a new Image I add a new listener to it with a new target field. Still the target field for all my listeners is the very last one that was assigned.

Comment: @markspace I should also add, that for some reason every Image that is added to the field has the same hashcode even though I add the newly created one at the end.

Comment: And `targetField` is a local variable?  You didn't change the code when you posted it here?  I'm surprised Java lets you do this, it's obviously broken.  Make `targetField` a field inside the listener, and assign it by passing the needed parameters in a constructor.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler isn't complaining about referencing a higher scoped, non-final variable in an anonymous class. Are you sure you're not missing any compiler errors/warnings? Either way I'd use the approach in @markspace's answer.

Comment: The code is ripped directly from the IDE. And even when `targetField` was inside the listener the same problem occurred.

Comment: That's latter statement -- the problem still occurs when `targetField` is inside the listener -- isn't feasible / possible.  There's something you're missing and not telling us.

Comment: Is there another `targetField` variable (possibly preceded by `final`) declared before the for loop? That's the only way I could see this code compiling.

Comment: There is no other `targetField` variable in the code at all. There are no errors or warnings as my code compiles without a problem. The main issue is that even without the target field thing, the actual field I click with the input listener is just the last one every time, even if I add each actor, it seems all actors remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `targetField` to the listener directly and initializing it with a constructor.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize[0]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mapSize[1]; j++) {
        hashCodes[i][j] = new Image(emptyField);
        hashCodes[i][j].addListener( new MyInputListener( i, j ) );
// rest of code...


class MyInputListener extends InputListener {
    int [] targetField = new int[2];
    InputListener( int i, int j ) {
      targetField[0] = i;
      targetField[1] = j;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(  // etc...
```

Comment: This does not work at all. I don't understand why you have called `class InputListener` but this just leads to errors on my part. Also `new InputListener ( i, j )` cannot work since the constructor for the InputListener class does not take int.

Comment: What constructor?  Isn't it an interface?  What API are you using?

Comment: Input Listener is a Class, Maybe you were thinking of EventListener.

Comment: By making some slight modifications to your code I managed to make it work. Meaning it didn't throw any more errors. Thanks for the push in the right direction